# Wave - Using Times as a Group

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

I am attempting to build a dashboard using times in the format hh:mm:ss AM/PM.  I have tried to do this several different ways include adding a date to the time (even though I don't need that because the report/dashboard is only for the current day), storing the time as text and creating helper columns for the hour and minutes.  None of the solutions have worked due to two constraints:

1. Wave doesn't seem to care about time unless you are using epoch_secs to find the difference between two dates

or

2. Wave doesn't sort dimensions (which are stored as text) the same way it would sort a number and/or date.  Instead it looks at the first character and sorts that way (example: 10 AM is placed prior to 2 AM instead of in the order of the time)

I am attempting display data in the order it occurred for the day using a column graph.  Anyone have any ideas?